# Equivalent of FileNotFoundError in OpenCV for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I've currently got a program that takes an input of a video file, and then will mask the colours so there are 3 different windows: one with only green showing, one with only yellow showing and one with only red showing. This part works fine, but I'm just trying to get it so that if it doesn't find a file at the given path, it will just use the webcam instead. I've tried using a `try except` statement using the FileNotFoundError, but that doesn't seem to work with OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

try:
    device = cv2.VideoCapture(r"%Downloads%\Traffic light changing between green yellow and red.mp4")
except FileNotFoundError:
    device = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = device.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_range_red = np.array([100,100,175])
    upper_range_red = np.array([255,255,255])
    lower_range_yellow = np.array([5,100,225])
    upper_range_yellow = np.array([50,255,255])
    lower_range_green = np.array([40,50,200])
    upper_range_green = np.array([120,200,255])

    mask_red = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range_red, upper_range_red)
    mask_yellow = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range_yellow, upper_range_yellow)
    mask_green = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range_green, upper_range_green)

    result_red = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask_red)
    result_yellow = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask_yellow)
    result_green = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask_green)
    cv2.imshow("Red",result_red)
    cv2.imshow("Yellow",result_yellow)
    cv2.imshow("Green",result_green)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27 & 0xFF:
        break

device.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: In the answer to the duplicate question `source` can be either a device number or a path to a file, so it works for this question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it is open correctly.

```
if device.isOpened()
```

Answer (score 1):

you could check whether the file exists using

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile(fname)
```

However, you don't get an exception.

Comment: Not a good idea. This could also try to open non-video files, or video with unsupported format

Comment: I just set the path as a variable, then used if `os.path.isfile(name) == True:` which would open the file, else open the webcam. That worked!